# Two methods with the same name in java

Tags: java, methods, extends

I noticed that if I have two methods with the same name, the first one accepts `SomeObject` and the second one accepts an object extending `SomeObject` when I call the method with `SomeOtherObject`, it automatically uses the one that only accepts `SomeObject`. If I cast `SomeOtherObject` to `SomeObject`, the method that accepts `SomeObject` is used, even if the object is an instanceof `SomeOtherObject`. This means the method is selected when compiling. Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's how method overload resolution in Java works: the method is selected at compile time.

For all of the ugly details, see [the Java Language Specification §15.12.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12)

Comment: @tbodt the word you were looking for is "polymorphic," and that's for method _overriding,_ not method _overloading._

Comment: I think it's more efficient that way: you don't loose time looking for the appropriate overload at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

> This means the method is selected when compiling.

Yes you are correct.  That is what it means.

> Why?

I can think of four reasons why they designed Java this way:

- This is consistent with the way that other statically typed OO languages that support overloading work.  It is what people who come / came from the C++ world expect.  (This was particularly important in the early days of Java ... though not so much now.).  It is worth noting that C# handles overloading the same way.
- It is efficient.  Resolving method overloads at runtime (based on actual argument types) would make overloaded method calls expensive.
- It gives more predictable (and therefore more easy to understand) behaviour.
- It avoids the Brittle Base Class problem, where adding adding a new overloaded method in a base class causes unexpected problems in existing derived classes.

References:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2004/01/07/virtual-methods-and-brittle-base-classes.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes the function to be executed is decided at compile time! So JVM has no idea of the actual type of the Object at compile time. It only knows the type of the reference that points to the object given as argument to the function.

For more details you can look into Choosing the [Most Specific Method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5) in Java Specification.

Comment: _"JVM has no idea of the actual type of the Object"_ is just not true. What do you think [`Object#getClass()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass()) returns?

Comment: That's at runtime and not at compile time. Compile time is the time when function to be executed is decided.

Comment: I don't see how that's related to the sentence I quoted.